# what pom.xml file is used for in a Storm project

Tags: maven

Am newbie working on some Apache Storm project. What pom.xml file is used for; what part of this file stays constant across projects and what part of this file needs to be specified for each project.

Comment: I think that this page may help you: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Great. This page is very informative. Thanks.